# Make the Textbox of wxSpinCtrl readonly in python

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, readonly

`wx.SpinCtrl` combines `wx.TextCtrl` and `wx.SpinButton` in one control. So it should be possible to make the textbox (`wx.TextCtrl`) of the spin-control readonly.

```
# not working:
self.spin_ctrl_1 = wx.SpinCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, "0", min=0, max=10, style=wx.TE_READONLY)
# not working:
self.spin_ctrl_1.SetEditable(False)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Looking at the docs I don't think this is supported. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Fixed minor formatting.

Comment: If you truly want to make it read-only, then defining it as a control becomes meaningless, unless it's solely for appearances. If that is the case, define it and disable it. `self.spin_ctrl_1.Enable(False)`. You can enable it at a later date, should you wish to.

Comment: That style is not provided. You can use instead a `wx.SpinButton` and a `wx.TextCtrl`, readonly, that you update on your own based on spinbutton events.

Comment: I agree with all the other comments. That said, if in whatever platform you are using the wx.SpinCtrl is a composite control (I.e., made with a spin button and a textctrl separately), then you *might* be able to do something like this: Control.GetChildren()[1].Enable(False).

Comment: I would like to do so, because the user should only be allowed to set values from the spin-range - or, in short words, just the up and down buttons should be enabled. Therefore the "control" is not just for appears, but stays a control, though.

Comment: The user can key in whatever they like but the spinctrl will restrict the input to whatever is within the minimum/maximum values. They should soon learn that their manual input is pointless.

Comment: @YUM, as `Rolf of Saxony` said. Also, keep in mind that you will be restrictig arrow keys for changing the value inside the control, which is not in par with you requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned in the comments, it's a bad idea to prevent the user from editing the text part of `wxSpinCtrl` -- this would be surprising and non-standard UI that would only annoy the users of the application. If you really, really want to do this, you should use `wxSpinButton` and `wxStaticText` updated with its value, but there should be no real problem with using `wxSpinCtrl` as its value is always constrained to the specified range.